# Is it possible to provide custom headers to the Safari View Controller

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

Is it possible to provide custom headers to the safari view controller.

I would like to pass an API key or authentication token with my request, and I cannot place it in the query string.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately no, it is (still) not possible with iOS <=12.

Someone requested this feature: 
http://www.openradar.me/33483701